# WiFi Parental controls for Private Address feature in IOS 14

Tags: router, internet

I have setup parental controls for certain devices on my WiFi and all works fine on the MAC address.
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211227

However, in iOS 14 there is a new privacy feature which changes the MAC address every day so it is randomized.

Any ideas how to ensure parental controls on WiFi is setup to handle this?

Otherwise I have to update the WiFi parental controls frequently which is a non starter.

Comment: You can disable this on a per-network basis [click the `i` symbol next to your home network in WiFi prefs], but idk if it can then be locked out with parental controls.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, I done this but can be enabled back on the device by the user so it's not a solution

Comment: You're going to have to look into the router settings. Potentially; fix known MAC addresses to individually-assigned IP addresses using the DHCP setup in the router, then set 'unknown' MAC addresses outside the fixed policy to a smaller, regular dynamic address pool; set any addresses from *inside* that dynamic pool to a 'child' or even 'guest' policy on there. That's all really going to depend on your router & ISP.

Comment: You might have to go the other way and see if your router has a "whitelist" option instead of the blacklist your parental controls are apparently using. That way they would only be able to connect with the normal MAC address rather than the randomised one.

Comment: This has been an extremely frustrating problem for my family. I want my Wifi to be open for guests, but I don't want our child using our iPad to have unlimited internet access. All he has to do, though, is turn on Private Address and there is no way to block the connection on the router by IP address, MAC address or host name. All the "answers" I've found so far have been to take the iPad away and hide it, apply Wifi restrictions for all devices, or scold myself as a parent for not getting a child that was born obedient. Yes, eventually he will learn, but meanwhile this misfeature is no help.

Comment: Complain to Apple. While there are parental controls on IOS, those controls do not allow you to lock "Randomize MAC" address setting into an off state. If Apple let you disable random MAC on the "home" network, then you would retain content controls at home, and still benefit from the anonymity feature when on public networks. Your other option is to enable parental controls for "All" devices on the network, except for certain (parent) devices.

Comment: @ScottPrive Have you tried complaining to Apple on the controls yet? Are you having a laugh, waste of time. So many gaps in their Screen time and parental controls, it's pointless. Their screen time is not universal for one and allow selected apps to circumvent it. That path is pointless unless governments take a strong stnace on legislation. Yes, if they allowed more control over "known" wifis then would have worked.

Comment: @Rubans Actually I have used feedback forms, and the user forums, to complain. Is what it is now, it's always up to the IOS beta-tester community to have complained earlier before this change got locked in.

Answer (score 1):

used whitelist and parent control were very cumbersome. I used guest wifi network for my child and disable it when I don't want him to access the internet. Apple had to think again for the private address configure for their devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).